Automation via icon on desktop (or dock?) of Terminal function .. ? End goal to differently-color all open Terminal windows

Would there be a way to have a file/icon of some sort of my desktop - (or, not as ideal but in the dock) which essentially opens a terminal window via the menu Shell -> New Window -> .. one of the profiles.
(The profiles you see "discotest" etc are simply plain Terminal windows, with different color backgrounds.)
Use ... when I have a few shells open to different places, as I open each one, I simply change the color so they are all different. (I do this so often I have the keystroke to bring up the color selector in finger memory!)
Thus, I'm wanting to have say three icons on my desktop, named red/green/blue and simply double-clicking one, opens Terminal -> menu Shell -> New Window -> SomeProfile
An alternative, perhaps even better, solution to the underlying problem, would thus be, an automation that choose a new random/whatever color each time you open yet another new Terminal window.
TY

A profile (setting set) has more than the background color, such as the font, window size, shell, terminal type, etc.  Several window properties are exposed to AppleScript - are you just wanting to change the window background color, or the profile?

just the color would be great!  "tap something to cycle the color", simple.  (to make differnt Terminal windows distinguisbablke)

An AppleScript can be used, for example:
# on run {args, parameters} -- use this declaration for a Run AppleScript action in Automator
on run args -- script run from the editor or Script Menu, or app double-clicked
   set useFinderSelection to false -- set to true to use the Finder selection if no arguments
   set processedItems to {}
   if args is not in {{}, missing value, current application, me} then -- command line or Automator arguments?
      repeat with anItem in args
         try
            set anItem to POSIX path of anItem
            if isDirectory(anItem) then
               doStuff("cd " & quoted form of anItem)
               set end of processedItems to anItem
            end if
         on error errmess -- oops
            log errmess
         end try
      end repeat
   else
      if useFinderSelection is true then set processedItems to doFinderSelection()
   end if
   if processedItems is {} then doStuff("") -- just the default working directory
end run

to doFinderSelection() -- handle folders in the current Finder selection
   tell application "Finder" to set theSelection to (get selection as alias list)
   set processedItems to {}
   repeat with anItem in theSelection
      if contents of anItem is not (path to me) then -- application will be selected if double-click
         set anItem to POSIX path of anItem
         if isDirectory(anItem) then
            doStuff("cd " & quoted form of anItem)
            set end of processedItems to anItem
         end if
      end if
   end repeat
   return processedItems
end doFinderSelection

to doStuff(theScript) -- open a new Terminal window with random background color, running theScript
   if application "Terminal" is running then
      set {r, g, b} to {16383 * (random number from 0 to 4), 16383 * (random number from 0 to 4), 16383 * (random number from 0 to 4)} -- 125 possible colors
      tell application "Terminal"
         activate
         do script theScript -- a script of "" just creates a new window
         set background color of window 1 to {r, g, b}
         if (r + g + b) / 3 > 21845 then -- try to make the text color contrast
            set normal text color of window 1 to {0, 0, 0} -- black
         else
            set normal text color of window 1 to {65535, 65535, 65535} -- white
         end if
      end tell
   else
      tell application "Terminal"
         launch -- avoid multiple windows
         do script theScript -- default window
         activate
      end tell
   end if
end doStuff

on isDirectory(posixPath) -- check if a file item is a directory or bundle
   set posixPath to quoted form of posixPath
   set determination to (do shell script "/usr/bin/file -b " & posixPath)
   if determination contains "directory" then return true
   return false
end isDirectory

on open fileItems -- items dropped onto the app (only needed for a droplet)
   repeat with anItem in fileItems
      set anItem to POSIX path of anItem
      if isDirectory(anItem) then doStuff("cd " & quoted form of anItem)
   end repeat
end open

Edit:
Updated the script to be able to be run from a script editor or the Script Menu*, from the command line via osascript, or saved as a script applet or droplet.  With a slight change to the run handler parameters, it can also be run from a Run Script action in Automator.  It looks for directories in any file arguments (command line or dropped onto the droplet, otherwise optionally the current Finder selection), and opens a new Terminal window with a random background color for each one found, running a script in the window that changes the working directory to the folder.  If there are no arguments or Finder selection, a new window is created at the default working directory.
*The Script Menu (enabled according to the Script Editor preference) is a status item menu on the right side of the main menu bar that uses scripts (or aliases to them) that you put in your user's ~/Library/Scripts folder.  If a script is placed in the main folder, it will always be in the menu, otherwise it can be placed in a folder named for the application in the Applications subfolder (create folders as needed), where it will only be in the menu when that application is active.

This is the way. +1 shortcuts can also call any Automator script or this and be added as a desktop widget or Notification Center widget for single click launching of this automation.

Amazing!  I'm a bit confused as to how to make that run, when, I click an icon on desktop but I'll figure it out !

@Fattie - From the Script Editor you can save it as an application, from Automator it can be placed in a Run AppleScript action and saved as an application.  My favorite for scripts is to put them in the Script Menu, then they are always available from a menu in the menu bar.

@red_menace amazing !

The shortcuts app lets you make all sorts of automations and save them to the desktop. Have you tried that to see if it gets you started on a solution?

https://support.apple.com/guide/shortcuts-mac/run-shortcuts-from-a-widget-apd029b36d05/mac


shortcuts app is fascinating.  i spent ten mins looking at it and, as i understand it it cant "click menu items" in an app it opens.  a solution seems to be to use javascript in a Shortcuts harness, as for example outlined here https://youtu.be/ScYZBoUDdAk?t=146  I put this comment in as it may help future googlers!

After searching on SE sites I did find another solution, mashing up some answers
(1) https://superuser.com/a/1201518/401734
to set a randomish color from the shell itself:
] osascript -e "tell application \"Terminal\" to set current settings of front window to some settings set"

(2) Lauching a Terminal '.command' file, without exiting session
tip by user @klanomath in the comments
using ".command" files to very easily launch a shell
Hence like:
(3) https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/474750/19991
In short, make a plain text file example.command, the contents of which is these four lines of text:
osascript -e "tell application \"Terminal\" to set current settings of front window to some settings set"
cd /Users/blah/Desktop/blah
ssh -i blah blah
$SHELL

Double click on the file.
All works perfectly and does literally exactly what asked in the question, if anyone else is looking for that:


Again, note that a settings set is an entire profile, which sets a lot more than colors.  If you aren't changing the profile, osascript can run any script to do stuff like set individual Terminal properties such as window colors, run a shell script, and/or work with arguments.  See the Terminal scripting dictionary for its commands and properties.

"See the Terminal scripting dictionary for its commands and properties" outstanding tip @red_menace, TY.  you know, there's only "so much time in the day" to spend on IDEs, CLIs, APIs, command sets, libraries, etc that are not in one's core competency, so, it's likely I'll never get to it :/  It would be cute to modify that osascript command so that it cycles rather than random occasionally repeats, but, when I started these QA (really, some years ago!) I had utterly no clue of the existence of ".command" files on Mac, so, my life is changed. I've used my shiny new xyz.command desktop file 10

0s of times already!  Tears of joy!

I went ahead and updated my answer so that the script can be run in different ways, with arguments that will set the current working directory.

